# Return CMD answer to variable in Python

Tags: python, cmd

I need to return the answer of CMD command to a variable in Python, I've try using a some OS modules but nothing them work propely.

E.G TASKLIST, I need return all data in CMD to a variable in Python, can be any command, just need the value

```
arp_inf = command(arp -a 192.168.100.1) 

print(arp_inf) # Ip Adress 192.168.100.1 Phisic Adress.....
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to capture the **output** of a command. Here is an example with `tasklist`:

```py
import subprocess
p = subprocess.run('tasklist', capture_output=True)

# p has the output in stdout and the error in stderr:
for line in p.stdout.splitlines():
    print(line)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I Want